# Would Ubuntu 13.10 work on unallocated space with Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi, gpt

I've not been able to find this answer anywhere else. Are you able to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1 on unallocated space? I did this with Windows 7, but I had to cover all of those partitions and make one primary for the Windows 8.1 installation. Thanks for an answer, if anyone replies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have some unallocated space on your hard drive, the Ubuntu installer will be able to use that for Ubuntu. Alongside Windows 8.1 on another partition.

The only thing that you should be aware of is that you can only create a maximum of 4 primary partitions on a hard drive. That is, if you already have 4 primary partitions, then you cannot use that unallocated space for Ubuntu, as Ubuntu will need to create at least one partition for itself.

(Note: Typically Ubuntu uses more than one partition, at least one for the root system and one for swap space; often for `/home`, sometimes for `/boot`, sometimes for other folders. But as long as you can allocate at least one primary partition on your hard drive, you could configure the Ubuntu installer to make it a logical partition that could again be split into four extended partitions.)

Comment: The four-primary-partitions rule applies only to the old [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system. Computers that ship with Windows 8 or 8.1 almost always use the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system, which has a 128-partition limit and no concept of primary, extended, or logical partitions. Computers on which you install Windows could conceivably use either system.